# Indexing a string,getting SyntaxError/Python

Tags: python, indexing, syntax-error

So when I do something like this :

```
    x=str(19072000)
    day=x[:2]
    month=x[2:4]
    year=x[4:]
    final=day+"/"+month+"/"+year
    print(final)
I get:19/07/2000

>>>x=str(01011930)
File"(Stdin)",line 1
x=str(01011930)
                       ^
SyntaxError:invalid token
```

But when i try to do the same thing but with 01011930 i get SyntaxError:invalid token,any ideas why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the leading `0` in your integer constant.

In Python 2, an integer that begins with a `0` is taken to be an octal constant, which doesn't allow the digits `8` or `9` (and even without them, the resulting number will be quite different from what you intend).

In Python 3, it isn't allowed at all, except for `0` itself.  (Octal constants begin with `0o` in Python 3, similar to how hex constants begin with `0x`.)

To do what you want, just remove the leading zero.  Then you can zero-pad using:

```
x = "%08d" % 1011930
```

This will set `x` to the string `'01011930'`.  Then your indexing will work.

Equivalently, you can use:

```
x = "{:08d}".format(1011930)
```

Comment: When i try to run the code with your solution in  command line it works,however when i try to do it in the eclipse it still gives me:
`r1=Radnik("Petar","Petrovic",1907000820015,01011930 ,"Senta","Srbija")
                                                                                       ^
SyntaxError: invalid token`


I have a class written for this,it works with any other date/numbers but with anything that starts with 0 it still won't work.

Comment: You didn't remove the leading zero, it's still there:  `01011930`.  You need to remove the leading zeros from all of your integer constants.  Change it to `1011930`.  The leading zeros are causing your syntax errors.